# Best way to set up a Datamodel or Schema Relationship using Ruby-on-Rails and Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, activerecord, data-modeling

I am creating a web application that allows a user to `track/log` their vehicle `restoration/maintenance` costs from hours allocated and purchased parts. I need help setting up the database schema and model relationships correctly. Please keep in mind, while I understand this can be simplified, I need to have a minimum of 5 models for this assignment.

Here's what I've come up with so far.
(VSP in the image is short for `Vehicle_Service_Part`, which is intended to be a "3 ID attribute table" link between the models Vehicle, Service, and Part.) While not shown in the schema code, each class will automatically be created with its own unique primary key `:id`.
I am 2 points short of being able to post images...please see data models at [link](https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7879/45906952925_36637573dc_b.jpg)

Here's my rails schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_01_21_042407) do
  create_table "owners", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "street"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "state"
    t.integer "zip"
    t.string "phone_number"
    t.string "email"
  end

  create_table "parts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "part_number"
    t.string "part_name"
    t.integer "cost"
    t.string "part_type"
    t.integer "quantity"
  end

  create_table "services", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "date"
    t.string "work_description"
    t.integer "car_miles"
    t.integer "work_hours"
  end

  create_table "vehicle_service_parts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "vehicle_id"
    t.integer "service_id"
    t.integer "part_id"
  end

  create_table "vehicles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "make"
    t.string "model"
    t.integer "year"
    t.string "vin"
    t.string "engine"
    t.string "car_type"
    t.string "color"
  end

  create_table "vendors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "contact"
    t.string "website"
    t.string "location"
  end
end
```

And here are my model relationships:

```
class Owner < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :vehicles
    has_many :vehicle_service_parts, through: :vehicles
end

class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :owner
    has_many :vehicle_service_parts
    has_many :services, through: :vehicle_service_parts
    has_many :parts, through: :vehicle_service_parts
end

class Service < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :vehicle_service_parts
    has_many :vehicles, through: :vehicle_service_parts
    has_many :parts, through: :vehicle_service_parts
end

class Part < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :vendor
    has_many :vehicle_service_parts
    has_many :vehicles, through: :vehicle_service_parts
    has_many :services, through: :vehicle_service_parts
end

class VehicleServicePart < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :vehicle
    belongs_to :service
    belongs_to :part
    has_many :owners, through: :vehicles
    has_many :owners, through: :parts
end

class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :parts
    has_many :vehicle_service_parts, through: :parts
end
```

Based on my models and their relationships, there are a few things that I would ultimately like to accomplish, some of which I think can already be reached using the given relationship setup, and others I unfortunately do not have much knowledge or skill on where to begin.

1. Owners can have multiple vehicles with different sets of records.
2. A Vehicle can have many services using a part, and ultimately have many parts from the many services.
3. The model class `Part` contains an attribute `:part_type` which will be assigned a string from a categorized list including but not limited to "engine", "suspension", "brakes"...etc. allowing a viewer to see all totaled parts/costs/hours/services of `:part_type "engine"` of a given vehicle.
4. When the viewer creates a new `Service`, I would like to be able to create a new instance of the class `Part` with perspective attribute data to be inputed through forms and then added to the database.
5. Would it be possible to accomplish 4. while also creating/adding multiple parts within one service? For example, an oil change will be considered a single instance of the class `Service` however will be associated with multiple instances of the class `Part` including an oil-filter instance and oil instance. Both oil-filter and oil are two different parts but housed under a single instance of service.
6. A viewer can see all different parts serviced on their car along with total costs.
7. A viewer can see all vendors where their cars parts have been purchased from.

Any help, direction, or advice will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for you would be to design the database like below:

1. owners -> has_many -> vehicles

   owners  <- belongs_to <- vehicles
2. vehicles -> has_many -> parts

   vehicles <- belongs_to <- parts (here based on your use case, vehicles and parts can also have many to many. You might have to use has_and_belongs_to_many relationship)
3. parts -> has_many -> services

   services <- belongs_to <- parts

For your 4th point, yes you can achieve this through accepts_nested_attributes_for concept. In your Service Create form, you can add fields for parts. Follow the guide here https://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/